# Dynamically show that a side menu has been selected

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem, selected

I have created a side menu in a WPF.  Here is the xaml:

```
        <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="1" Margin="2" Stroke="Black" />
        <MenuItem Header="Remove Headers" Click="MenuItem_Click_RH" />
        <MenuItem Header="Get Headers" Click="MenuItem_Click_GH" />
        <MenuItem Header="Count Delimiters" Click="MenuItem_Click_CNTD" />
        <Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />
        <MenuItem Header="Close" Click="MenuItem_Click_Close" />
    </Menu>
```

Here is my click code:

```
        private void MenuItem_Click_CNTD(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //***  Count Delimiters Menu Click  ***

            // ... Cast sender object.
            System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem item = sender as System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem;
            // ... Change Title of this window.
            Title = "Process " + item.Header + " Files";


            lblDCTitle.Content = "Process to get mumber of delimiters in a large file.";
            grdHeaderRows.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            mnuSideMenu.Height = 360;
            grdMain.Height = 360;
            grdDelimiterCount.Height = 400;
            grdDelimiterCount.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

This all works fine but I would like to highlight the menu item that was clicked.  I cannot find code to do this.  Anyone have any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks #Alexandru Turcan for your suggestion.  I was able to do it this way, I do not have many menu items and this works perfectly for me.  I put this code in each of my menu_click routines.

```
 miRH.Background = SystemColors.ControlDarkBrush;
 miGH.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 232, 249, 246));
 miCD.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 232, 249, 246));
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first. How do you want to highlight the item? If you want to change its background brush The first thing that came to mind is to set the background brush of the clicked `menuitem`, but this will be super hard-coded, because you'l have to set background brush in every click event handler.

Another, more optimized version of the first option is to:

- Have 2 Brushes defined (One DefaultColor, other SelectedColor);
- Have all menu items in a `List<MenuItems>` ( you can get them by from `YourMenu.Children` property.
- Have an eventhandler subscribed to every menu item. You can do it like this: `YourMenuItemName.Click+=YourEventHanderName`.
  The event handel will change the color of the clicked item to the SelectedColor and to the DefaultColor brush for the rest of MenuItems;

Pretty hardcoded, but somehow more dynamic then previous version.